# how to validate range of numbers in RAML（half-open interval）

Tags: validation, range, mule, raml

I defined a raml file.
I want to valid a queryParameter(coefficient) that greater than 0 and less than or equal to 1.
**(0＜ coefficient  ≦ 1 )**

Here is my raml.

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: sample API
baseUri: http://localhost:8081/api
version: 1.0
/inventory:
    get:      
      coefficient:
        type: number
        minimum: 0
        maximum: 1
```

I use the **minimum** and **maximum** but this will make 0 possible.
How can I set the validation to greater than 0, but not equal to 0.

Any ideas?
(For some reasons I have to use the number type.I know with type string and regex may solve this problem as a work around.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RAML specification doesn't seem to define ranges clearly but it looks to me that the current version of the specification (RAML 1.0) doesn't has the expressive power to differentiate a half-open interval nor an open interval.

The [RAML 1.0 specification](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md#number) just says:

```
Facet   Description 
minimum?    The minimum value. 
maximum?    The maximum value.
```

If you want to enforce this validation you will need to implement it in the API implementation instead of its RAML definition.